# Is PHP opcode forwards compatible?

Tags: php, pecl

I'm writing a PECL extension that in part will run PHP opcode directly from file, I was wondering, is it reasonable to assume opcode produced in PHP 5.4 will run in PHP 5.6?

A list of opcode names can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.php) for the latest version on PHP/Zend, I'm guessing these names *are* forwards compatible - i.e. the authors probably won't remove an opcode but is the raw opcode generated by PHP forwards compatible?

Comment: Looking at the GitHub history of the Zend C file containing the opcodes here https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_vm_opcodes.c it appears the authors have made an effort to retain opcode names and opcode numbers matching up between PHP versions...can anyone confirm this?

Comment: At a quick look it looks compatible, but would would lose any optimisations from the php compiler to opcode which may come in the future. Why run the op code and not just the php ?

Comment: @exussum Thanks, yes I agree, up to date opcode is preferable. The extension is to protect PHP source so that's why! Having said that I suspect people don't often update the PHP version on their servers.